# server setup with elastic search, monit, redis, memcached (along with apache) for rails app on Linode

Tags: redis, elasticsearch, linode

I have 2 VPSes on linode and 1 node balancer. 1 DB Vps and 1 App Vps. I send things through my nodebalancer so it's easier to scale out the app servers eventually.My question is 2 fold:

1. Do you guys suggest I just drop memcached and use redis for caching? I'm using redis for other things (such as resque) and this would make my infrastruture that much simpler.
2. I also intend to use redis as a session store. When I'm ready to add another application server vps, is it possible to make it seem like 1 virtual redis store across the 2 VPSes? This is also important for caching.

Also do you suggest I install redis, elastic search, monit on each VPS or should I have a separte VPS for these services and another one for my Application server?

Many thanks.